# How to make an API get request with credential and certificates in Python?

Tags: python, ssl

I am trying to make an API call to secured site. Username, password, certificate were given.
My code is throwing errors:

> (ssl.SSLError: [SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL] ee key too small (_ssl.c:3905)).

I increased the key using openssl. I am getting the same error again.
I am new to Python.

```
 cert_path = "C:/python/demo.cer"  
    key_path = "C:/python/demo.key"  
    passphrase = "name123"
    
    username = "username"
    password = "Password"
    
    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile=cert_path, keyfile=key_path, password=passphrase)
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers= headers, params=params, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), cert=(cert_path, key_path), verify="C:/python/demo.cer")



Traceback (most recent call last):
 Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen        
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request  
    self._validate_conn(conn)
 Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
 site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 Python311\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 418, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL] ee key too small (_ssl.c:3905)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 \site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Python311\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='download.finratraqs.org', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url:(Caused by SSLError(SSLError(399, '[SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL] ee key too small (_ssl.c:3905)')))
```

Comment: I'm out of my depth, but you should probably post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).